# How to divide a div into sections (working with min-height 100%)?

Tags: css, html

I am using the following lay-out: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

Right now, I'm trying to create something like this: http://imgur.com/P64BojY

What I would like to have is a header, two divs in the middle of the page and a fixed footer. All of the divs (except for the footer) should be of the same size.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to divide the central div (from the lay-out I've mentioned before) into two divs of the same size, I need the footer to stay at the bottom of the page though.

For my other pages I'll need to be using the same lay-out, except for the bottom div, which has to be divided in 3 divs, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwWe6.jpg

I'm not sure how to do any of this, since I'm working with the min-height 100%...

So yeah... any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want? easier to just show you a jsfiddle so you check the css needed.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="containerDivs">
    <div class="div1">
           div1
    </div>    
    <div class="div2">
            div2
    </div> 
</div>     

<div class="footer">
        footer
</div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QcG7a/

Comment: If you want to add a header, just make a div above "containerDivs", give it xxPX as height and add same px amount as "padding-top" to containerDivs

Comment: modified fiddle with 3 divs... (that's can't be exactly same size... just 33%, 33% and 34%) http://jsfiddle.net/QcG7a/1/

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working so far. 

Another question, I want the header to be an image, not sure what I should do to the image to make it fit though, the original image is 960x218. If i use this image it's obviously much smaller than the header itself. If I use a bigger image, say 3000x1000 px, it shows just a small part of the image in the header. (zoomed in)

Is there a way to use an image for the header in this lay-out, or is my only option using a pattern/seamless background?

Comment: and.. what if I want a class within a class? For example, i want some text to appear in div 1 but when I try to create a new class for this (to change the way the text looks) it gets all messed up, since div 1 is a class as well.

Comment: You have to include the image as html (<img> tag) and not as background-img for browse compatibility (I avoid to use background-size as much as possible). Then add "overflow:hidden" to the div you want to put the image in. Finally add css property to the image calling it with the class ".div1 img" ".header img", etc. Put height:100% if your image is portrait or width:100% if it's a landscape. If you use BOTH it will always fit the img to the div BUT it will distort the image. up to you. here you have an example:http://jsfiddle.net/QcG7a/2/

Comment: your second question is html and css basics. I would recomend you to follow some of the multiples tutorials online to get the easy concepts... but the answer: include whatever tags you want into your div... or make another div into the div. if it's just plain text use <p> tag (block element) or <span> tag (inline element). then add a class to the tag and call it on your css sheet to give it style. example:http://jsfiddle.net/QcG7a/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, I have replaced div content with two divs with class content

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<style>
html, body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808080;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    font: 1.5em georgia,serif;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
h2 {
    font: 1.25em georgia,serif;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em;
}
h1, h2, a {
    color: #FFA500;
}
p {
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}
div#container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F0F0F0;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
}
div#header {
    background: url("../csslayout.gif") no-repeat scroll 98% 10px #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 6px double #808080;
    padding: 1em;
}
div#header p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0;
}
#a{padding: 1em 1em 0em 1em;}
#b{padding: 0em 1em 6em 1em;}

div#content p {
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-align: justify;
}
div#footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
    border-top: 6px double #808080;
    bottom: 0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

div#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer</h1> 
            <p>Sometimes things that used to be really simple with tables can still appear pretty hard with CSS. This layout for instance would consist of 3 cells; two with a fixed height, and a third one in the center filling up the remaining space. Using CSS, however, you have to take a different approach.</p>
        </div>
        <!--div content duplicated-->
        <div class="content" id="a">
           <h2>Min-height</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="b">
           <h2>Min-height</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>
              This footer is absolutely positioned to bottom:0; of  #container. The padding-bottom of #content keeps me from overlapping it when the page is longer than the viewport.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The divs A and B aren't of the same size here..Thank you though!